# How do I increase the number of circle vertices? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I have a circle mesh but I need to increase the number of vertices. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In *Edit Mode*, select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>), right click and choose **"*Subdivide*"** (<kbd>W</kbd> if you use right click for select), then open the boxed dialog at the bottom left of the Viewport (also "*Edit > Adjust last operation*") and increase ***Smoothness* to 1.0**. You can select the multiplier (number of subdivisions) too.

[image]

---

Alternatively, at the moment of creation of the circle (top of Viewport, *Add > Mesh > Circle*) you had the option of selecting the number of vertices: this is done again by opening the boxed dialog at the bottom left of the Viewport and changing the number of vertices. But it can't be done once you have done any other operation.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes thank you it works all the ways :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, Blender has a very good community

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: But it would be good to add a button that can change the parameters of the object before applying modifiers :)

Comment: After the moment it gets created, the mesh is not a "Circle" anymore. It's a bunch of vertices and edges that happen to have been originally created in a circular arrangement. If you edit anything, Blender can't know that re-applying the "creation" step won't break your edits done meanwhile. Therefore you can't change "creation" parameters after edit, but you can do other options (that *don't* depend on it being a circle) like subdivide.